# Is there a way to convert API PDF Code response into PDF in Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-conversion

Using API I can obtain the PDF Coding for the invoice - in python I could write this response string directly in pdf and create therefore formatted document.

Is there a way to write this PDF code into PDF in google app script and get pdf formatted file?

Python Code Example (I need the same in google app script)

```
    for list_invoice in list_invoices['invoices']:
        response = requests.get('https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/invoices/'+str(list_invoice['invoice_id'])+'?organization_id=41285962&accept=pdf',
            headers = {
            "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            "Authorization" : "Zoho-oauthtoken "+authoken
            }
            )
        #getting pdf response - writing pdf encoding and making respective pdf invoice on the desktop

        with open('/Users/office/Desktop/'+str(invoice_number_hellocash_zoho)+'.pdf', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
```

Here is the google app script.

I get the error - Conversion from text/plain to application/pdf failed.

```
  var url = 'https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/invoices/'+invoice_data+'?organization_id=41285962&accept=pdf';
  var data = {
      "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
      "Authorization" : "Zoho-oauthtoken "+refresh_token_correct
  }
  var options = { "method":"GET",
                 "headers" : data
                };
  var pdf_encoded_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var pdf_encoded_response_content = pdf_encoded_response.getContentText();
  var pdfContent = pdf_encoded_response_content;
  var intermediate = DriveApp.createFile('tempFile',pdfContent,MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
  var blob = intermediate.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  Logger.log(blob.getContentType());
  var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  DriveApp.getFileById(intermediate.getId()).setTrashed(true);
```

Comment: You can save to your drive. Use `UrlFetchApp` and `DriveApp.createFile`

Comment: @Madhurjya thanks for your answer. I tried, but however, it appeared that I cannot insert the code to pdf. It is being inserted as text. Could you maybe help me with that? Because I need to insert the whole code not just a string

Comment: Can you show us your `Google Apps Script` code?

Comment: `pdf_encoded_response` is where your file is. You need to apply `getBlob()` function after `UrlFetchApp` and save that blob using `DriveApp`

Comment: @Madhurjya could you please show a sample?

UPD - I got it, thx! :)

Comment: 1. Fetch your file :  `var pdf_encoded_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getBlob()`   2. Save your file : `var file = DriveApp.createFile(pdf_encoded_response)`